# Understanding copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I am trying to understand the concept of copy constructors in C++. I have written the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box{
    private:
        int d;
    public:
        Box(int i){
            cout << "Constructor" << endl;
            d = i;
        }
        Box(const Box &old){
            cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl;
            d = old.d;
        }
        int getd(){
            return d;
        }
        ~Box(){
            cout << "Destructor" << endl;
        }
        Box operator+(const Box& op){
            Box c(15);
            c.d = d + op.d;
            return c;
        }
};

int main(){
    Box a(10);
    Box b = a;
    Box c = a+b;
    cout << c.getd() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
Constructor
Copy Constructor
Constructor
20
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

I don't understand why the copy constructor isn't getting called for the third line in the `main` function. I think that there should be a call to the copy constructor as `operator+` function returns by value.

Comment: Why do you mark "copy constructor" with code formatting? Weird.

Comment: I was trying to watch how those functions are getting called.

Comment: No, I mean, in the body of your question. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is optimising out the copy constructor call here, because the standard explicitly allows that copy to be "elided". What would be the point in such a copy, really?

You're absolutely right though, in that it's an *opportunity* for invocation of the copy constructor, and the compiler *could* do it. In fact, the standard does require that invoking the copy constructor be valid here.

Comment: Compiler can call move on line three for optimization.

Comment: @jaklucky: The OP's type has no move constructor (`[C++11: 12.8/9]`).

Comment: And if it did, it's not an optional optimization. If it doesn't elide, the compiler *must* call the move constructor instead of the copy constructor where it is applicable.

Comment: ... making it not really an "optimisation" at all.